# No root node is created in Realtime firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

no root node is created in Realtime database.
All the depenedencies are implemented and firebase is connected to the project.
this is code.

public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {

```
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Users user =new Users(binding.usernameTextView.getText().toString(),
                                binding.emailTextView.getText().toString(),binding.passwordTextView.getText().toString());

                        String id =  task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                         database.getReference().child("Users").child(id).setValue(user);


                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Sign Up is sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Usually Firebase prints out logs, have you seen any ? If the authorization failed, it usually says it there.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire code that you are using to add data to the database. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that has anything to do with your code. It does a second or 2 for the data to show up in my console as well. Make sure your internet connection is working fine.

Try the following:

1. Try another browser
2. Try using [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns)
3. Log out and Login again.

I had similar issue last year and here's the reply I had received from Firebase support:

> We've seen multiple reports about similar issues, and from what we have found so far is that this is very likely a network issue, related to the internet provider. Some users mention that this happens only with Reliance Jio; by any chance, is this your internet provider?
>
> Now, one user reported a DNS error, so one thing to try is using
> public DNS servers to verify if this is the issue. For example, from
> Google, you can use these: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (click here for more
> details).
>
> Finally, if that confirms it, what I suggest is to open the browser's
> developers tools and to gather the logs from the "Network" tab when
> you go to the Database Dashboard and get in touch with your provider
> to ask about this. I'll check the team to see what we can do, but
> getting in touch with the provider looks like the best option at this
> moment.